# Spring 3 validation method not validating

Tags: validation, forms, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm having some issues finding out how to validate in spring 3.
What i have so far is this Java Bean....

```
public class User {

@NotEmpty
@Size(min=2, max=40)
private String name="";

@Email
private String email="";

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}

public void setName(String name){

    this.name=name;
}

public void setEmail(String email){

    this.email=email;
}
```

}

This is the method that links to the page containing the form:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/form", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String form(Model model){


    model.addAttribute("user",new User());
    return "form";
}
```

And this is the method in my controller, which "should" validate

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/displayUser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String displayUser(Model model,@Valid User user,BindingResult result){


    if(result.hasErrors()){
       return "form";   
    }
    userList.add(user);
    model.addAttribute("user",user);

    return "displayUser";
}
```

The @Validate annotation should make the validation, but in my case it does not.

Do you see something wrong in my code?

by the way this is the form i have "all is very simple, this is just for test purposes

```
   <f:form method="post" action="displayUser" commandName="user">
 <table align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
  <td>Your details</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><f:label path="name">Name:</f:label></td><td><f:input path="name" /></td><f:errors path="name"></f:errors>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><f:label path="email">Email:</f:label></td><td><f:input path="email" /></td><f:errors path="name"></f:errors>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
  <td><input type="submit" value="register" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</f:form>
```

Any advise? (i use java 5 and there the javax.validation.Validator isn't available)

Comment: Tip: This isn't related to validation, but instead of manually placing the User on the Model, you can apply the @ModelAttribute annotation to the User parameter and it will automatically show up on the Model.

Comment: Hi Willie, the problem is that i cannot use the @ModelAttribute("user")User user, and @Valid User user, in the same parameter-list in the method signature, ofcourse ony one user variable its allowed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add javax.validation's validation-api and hibernate validator. If you use maven add the following on your dependencies:

```
           <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            </dependency>


             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
            </dependency>
```

Enable Spring annotation driven on your applicationContext

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Hi gouki, thx for the advise, Spring's annotations are already activated, i dont use Maven or Ants, the dependencies you have mentiond here above are already in the classpath of my project